# cannot install browse-sync on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, npm, browser-sync

I installed nodejs and and npm. Tried installing browser-sync with the command 
`npm install -g browser-sync` but got an error

```
    npm install -g browser-sync
npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-101-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "browser-sync"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
npm ERR! network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/krishna/npm-debug.log`
```

cant figure out whats wrong. Help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you are having internet connection problem

> `npm ERR! network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443`

1. make sure that you are connected to the internet
2. if you are behind a proxy, 'proxy' config is set properly. See: `npm help config`

Comment: Im not behind a proxy and the internet works just fine :(

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are having connection problems.

Try to use the ping tool to check your connection to check your connection:

```
ping google.com
```

Your issue can be a lot of things: proxy, a disconnected cable, dns. 
Can be a problem on Ubuntu too, to solve it's worth to try restart the network-manager

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```